# First letter of month in DateTime.ToString() with custom IFormatProvider

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting, tostring

Is there a way in DateTime format strings to have include just the first letter of the month?

```
new DateTime(2015, 1, 12).ToString("M-dd-yy") // "1-12-15",  but I want "J-02-15"
new DateTime(2000, 11, 7).ToString("M-dd-yy") // "11-07-00", but I want "N-17-00"
```

If not, is there some way to add a new, custom format to the system-wide IFormatProvider to handle this?

**Note for the "why are you trying to do it that way?" people:** This is for a vendor's chart control, **which only accepts a format string**. We are trying to make these dates as short as possible, and they are for international users, so numbers for the month won't work. I can't pass in a new IFormatProvider, so I would have to somehow **modify the existing IFormatProvider** (hopefully without breaking it).

Comment: what about January, July, June, etc?

Comment: You can use custom format using this override of ToString() : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64(v=vs.110).aspx but you need to define your own Format provider

Comment: @ibiza This is labeling values on the x-axis of a chart, so the user will see J,F,M,A,M,J,J,A,S,O,N,D all together and in order.

Comment: huh, never realized `JASON` was in the months.

Comment: Can't you just parse the date in a common format (like month/date/year) , and apply some regex to get only the first letter of the month ?

Comment: @Alexander Please see the note for the "why are you trying to do it that way?" people.

Comment: If it _has_ to be a format string, then the best you can do is `MMM` to get the first 3 letters of the month. Is that not short enough?

Comment: Are you restricted to passing a format string to the vender's control, or can you also pass an [IFormatProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: If numbers won't work for international users, what makes you think the letter `J` will be satisfactory? Your best option probably is `MM-dd-yy`.

Comment: @Matt no, I can't pass in a new IFormatProvider.

Comment: @DrewKennedy MM-dd-yy is ambiguous for international users - many are used to the day being first. See my comment to ibiza concerning `J`s and `A`s.

Comment: Whenever I display dates I try to go with yyyy-mm-dd. I assume this is no good for your use case though.

Comment: @christophano `yyyy-MM-dd` is a fair bit longer (3 characters) than desired and is not the easiest to read. `MMM-dd-yy` is 2 characters longer than desired. We may end up having to do that, but it's not ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using a customized `FormatProvider`:

```
    public static class SingleLetterMonthNameFormatter
    {
        private static IFormatProvider _formatProvider;
        public static IFormatProvider FormatProvider
        {
            get
            {
                if (_formatProvider == null)
                {
                    var dtfi = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
                    dtfi.AbbreviatedMonthNames = dtfi.MonthNames.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault().ToString()).ToArray();
                    _formatProvider = dtfi;
                }
                return _formatProvider;
            }
        }
    }
```

You can use it like this:

```
var monthName = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM", SingleLetterMonthNameFormatter.FormatProvider) //First letter of month name
```

If there's no way to pass a `FormatProvider` to the method you want, there's a nasty way to do it, use with care!

```
    var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;
    currentCulture.DateTimeFormat = SingleLetterMonthNameFormatter.FormatProvider as DateTimeFormatInfo;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM"));
```

Comment: Nice solution, I didn't realize the current culture instance was public. You should probably add some info about what this could break (any other calls on that thread to DateTime.ToString that actually want to use the abbreviated 3 letter month name) and also note that this will not work if the vender is calling ToString on another thread

Comment: Your and n0rd's answers get really close. Unfortunately, the vendor is using another thread to call ToString(). But your answer helps demonstrate that, without access to the vendor's separate thread, there is in fact no way to modify ToString()'s behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Let's dig a bit into `DateTime.ToString()` implementation. When no `IFormatProvider` object is passed to it, it will use `System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo` as the [`DateTimeFormatInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) object to get information on how to build string representation. `CurrentInfo`, in turn, gets it from `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`.

So you'd want to set up current thread culture in a way, that it has one character month names (or abbreviations as in example below), then use regular format string. One way to achieve this is the following:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

namespace DTFTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dt = DateTime.Now;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("EN-US", true);
            var ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            var monthNames = new[] { "J", "F", "M", "A", "M", "J", "J", "A", "S", "O", "N", "D", string.Empty };
            ci.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames = monthNames;
            Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MMM-dd-yyyy"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`(new DateTime(2015,1,12).ToString("MM")[0])+(new DateTime(2015,1,12).ToString("-dd-yy"))`

But be careful with months with the same first letter (January vs. July) and it may be better or worse depending on other cultures.

Comment: The `M` specifier get the month as a number

Comment: _"This is for a vendor's chart control, which only accepts a format string"_ - ie I don't think you can do anything other than specify a format string to properly answer this question - I'm not sure it's answerable.

Comment: I missed the chart control part. If that's the case, I think this won't work. Microsoft doesn't provide this option because J = January, July, A = April, August, etc.